# Polymorphism over argument values (not types)?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, polymorphism, language-design

Is there a programming language (may be a concept or research paper), which allows 
a polymorphism over function/method arguments values? Kind of:

```
function factorial(int value > 0){ /* code here */}
function factorial(int value == 0){ /* code here */}
function factorial(int value < 0){ /* code here */}
```

And, what is the official name, if any,  for this kind of polymorphism?

Comment: I think there may be some leads starting from [(value) dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), at least for more "academic purposes". There are some dependent-typed languages, but I do not know what sort of support they have for (and what kind of) polymorphism. Guards *generally* aren't the same as they are often a "pretty way" of writing an `if-else` (e.g. arguably not polymorphic), but this will vary depending on language.

Comment: Also check out the base [polymorphism (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) wikipedia entry (not the OO one which is already boxed into subtype polymorphism) which shows *parametric polymorphism* (and indicates my claim above about "guards generally [not being polymorphic]" is context specific, at the least ;-)

Comment: Loads: Haskell comes to mind first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is *pattern matching* and/or *guards*. Erlang for instance allows this:

```
foo(X) when X > 0  -> bar(X);
foo(X) when X == 0 -> baz(X);
foo(X)             -> X.

foo("bar", X) -> bar(X);
foo(42, X)    -> baz(X);
foo(_, X)     -> X.
```

The former demonstrates the use of guards, the latter is a simple pattern match, where the first argument is either `"bar"`, `42` or anything else. Both techniques can be found in many functional languages.

Just in case you're not familiar with the syntax, that's equivalent to (as much as it can be compared):

```
function foo("bar", x) {
    return bar(x);
}
function foo(42, x) {
    return baz(x);
}
...
```

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that, unlike the techniques that are usually referred to as polymorphism, pattern matching does not allow you to add cases "after the fact". I.e. if you define a function with one case for positive integers and one for zero, you can't just add a third case for negative numbers in a different file/compilation unit.

Comment: @sepp2k Depends on language I believe (that is, there is no reason why this *couldn't* work in [dynamic] languages, such as one of the numerous Lisp dialects). I do not now enough about the various "Lisp OO" flavors, however.

Comment: @pst True, I should have added "in any language I'm aware of".

Answer (score 2):

There's a 2006 paper by Matthias Blume called "Extensible Programming with First-Class Cases" that talks about such a system (based on ML, IIRC).

You might be able to do the same sort of thing with some aspect-oriented languages like AspectJ, but I haven't tried it.

Also, in languages like Scheme that support both first-class functions and mutation of names bound to functions, you can extend a function by wrapping the old version:

```
(define (factorial n)
  1)

(factorial 0) ;; => 1
(factorial 5) ;; => 1

(set! factorial
  (let ([old-factorial factorial])
    (lambda (n)
      (cond [(> n 1)
             (+ (factorial (- n 1)) (factorial (- n 2)))]
            [else
             (old-factorial n)]))))

(factorial 0) ;; => 1
(factorial 5) ;; => 8
(factorial 6) ;; => 13
```

Redefining a function is accepted for debugging but frowned upon for "real code", and some module systems don't allow mutation of module exports. In that case, an alternative is to have a private mutable variable containing the list of cases; the main function explicitly goes through the cases, and there is a separate function for adding cases.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching and guards is one way of doing this; OCaml, Haskell, and Scala all provide them as well.

Prolog has a similar feature: you can define relations that depend on specific values. For example:

```
factorial(X, 0) :- X =< 0, !.
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(X, Y) :- X2 is X - 1, factorial(X2, Z), Y is X * Z.
```

In this code, we define a `factorial` relation such that `factorial(X,Y)` is satisfied when Y=X!; to do so, we specialize it over three cases, one involving a specific value and another involving a range test.

Yep, Prolog is really weird. Programming consists of writing down true statements; you then query the system for the truth of a particular statement or a variable assignment which makes a statement true. For example, if the above code is saved in `factorial.pl`:

```
?- consult(factorial).
% factorial compiled 0.00 sec, 2,072 bytes
true.

?- factorial(3, 6).
true .

?- factorial(5, X).
X = 120 .

?- factorial(4, 25).
false.
```